# Is there a way to arbitrarily pick one result in SQL query without doing GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large SQL query in SQL Server 2014 with many columns and joins and have simplified it here below. The join to the Goals table involves a date range and if there are overlapping date ranges, it's possible two or more records will be linked to. If that happens, I just want to arbitrarily pick one, like the minimum or the first. Doesn't matter. Is there a good way to do this without doing a Group By? In other words, without doing a Group By on a.ID and then doing a MIN on GoalValue?  The real life scenario involves avoiding bad data in my database. I'll resort to a Group By if I have to.

```
select a.ID, g.GoalValue
from Table1 a
join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
left join Goals g on g.ID = b.ID
        and b.BeginDate between g.StartDate and g.EndDate

Sample Data for Goals table:

ID  |  GoalValue  |  StartDate  | EndDate
1         5          1/1/2000    12/31/2000
1         6          6/1/2000    9/1/2000
1         10         1/1/2001    12/31/2009
1         12         1/1/2010    12/31/2050
2         100        1/1/2000    12/31/2050
3         50         1/1/2000    12/31/2005
3         75         1/1/2006    12/31/2050
```

If ID = 1 and the BeginDate value is 8/1/2000, then records with Values 5 and 6 will be returned. But I only want one row. One record is bad data I may not be able to delete in the short term.

Comment: please show some sample data and tag the dbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the answer from @KeithS using TOP 1. If you truly don't care about which row is selected, then TOP 1 should deliver the most performant results. However I feel that the example given is harder to extrapolate into a more complex query and doesn't allow you to use aggregations on the joined list.

If the issue is that in the joined table, you only want 1 row, then you need to specify a TOP 1 on that joined table only, not on the entire recordset.

You can use a nested select to achieve this however I find that the syntax of the Apply statements to be cleaner:

```
select TOP 1 a.ID, g.GoalValue
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
outer apply (
    SELECT TOP 1 GoalValue 
    FROM Goals 
    WHERE Goals.ID = t2.ID 
      and t2.BeginDate between Goals.StartDate and Goals.EndDate
) g
```

Note that apply gets evaluated differently to nested tables, and depending on the where clause it may not be as efficient as a group by or nested query. Apply is best suited for containing inline functions and ensuring that they are executed once per row in the record set, which can make them less performant in set based logic. If using Apply and are expecting optimal results try not to filter on the fields returned by the apply statement, or try to filter as many rows as you can before filtering on the result fields from the apply. In this example either do not include a filter on GoalValue, or if you must filter on GoalValue, make that the last condition in your where criteria
See ["Using APPLY"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on MSDN

> NOTE: inside the apply query you are free to use aggregations, such as AVE(g.GoalValue) instead of TOP 1 without also having to specify a grouping statement.
>
> WARNING: Don't use Row_Number() or other windowing techniques in sub queries as described here to get the first row or calculate averages, this doesn't add any extra value than a simple top 1, it complicates the syntax and has performance impact.

```
outer apply (
    SELECT AVE(GoalValue)
    FROM Goals 
    WHERE Goals.ID = t2.ID 
      and t2.BeginDate between Goals.StartDate and Goals.EndDate
) g
```

Here is the same query with a nested select for comparison

```
select TOP 1 a.ID, g.GoalValue
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
left join (
    SELECT TOP 1 GoalValue 
    FROM Goals 
    WHERE Goals.ID = t2.ID 
      and t2.BeginDate between Goals.StartDate and Goals.EndDate
) g
```

Even though the syntax is almost identical, the execution plan for these two queries can be vastly different. You mentioned that your particular query was more complex that what you posted so trial a few variants of what is listed here and let us know which one best suited your scenario!

Comment: Minor gripe, please don't use arbitrary alias names in SQL queries! make the alias meaningful so that later you don't confuse a.ID, b.ID, c.ID. If you can't read the SQL statement and implicitly know which table is a,b,c... then choose a better alias. Even in examples, most of us developers learn from examples, so lets make sure all the examples out there don't result in lazy code habits. - that's why I altered the alias for Table1 and Table2 - changing the world one SQL query at a time. :)

Comment: Thanks! I used the OUTER APPLY method and instead of doing Top, I'm doing Min(GoalValue) after realizing that is more likely to bring back the correct (non bad data) result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "TOP 1" (T-SQL) or "LIMIT 1" (most other DBMSes) clause in your query. The engine will then simply return the first row it encounters.

T-SQL:

```
select TOP 1 a.ID, g.GoalValue
from Table1 a
join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
left join Goals g on g.ID = b.ID
        and b.BeginDate between g.StartDate and g.EndDate
```

Oracle, MySql, Postgre, etc:

```
select a.ID, g.GoalValue
from Table1 a
join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
left join Goals g on g.ID = b.ID
        and b.BeginDate between g.StartDate and g.EndDate
LIMIT 1
```

This will give you a fairly deterministic result, based on the engine's query plan and any additional conditions or clauses.

Comment: Sorry I didn't list until now that I was using SQL Server 2014. Unfortunately Top won't work unless I somehow use it on the join to Goals. There are a lot of other records in there. Beginning to think I should suck it up and use a GROUP BY

Comment: Im guessing that his inteded result to force the join on one record even if it matches two

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to achieve this I can think of.

Here is my mock schema and data since you didn't provide any:

```
declare @Tbl table (
    Id int primary key,
    BeginDate date not null
);

declare @Goals table (
    Id int not null,
    GoalValue int not null,
    StartDate date not null,
    EndDate date not null
);

insert into @Tbl (Id, BeginDate)
values
(1, '20150101'),
(2, '20160101'),
(3, '20170101'),
(4, '20170224');

insert into @Goals (Id, GoalValue, StartDate, EndDate)
values
(1, 25, '20141015', '20151102'),
(1, 74, '20141231', '20151111'),
(2, 182, '20150704', '20151123'),
(3, 11, '20160701', '20170630'),
(4, 248, '20160701', '20170630'),
(4, 15, '20160701', '20170209'),
(4, 7, '20170101', '20180101');
```

There is a very neat trick in T-SQL to get first rows from multiple groups without cluttering your code with subqueries or aggregation: the `with ties` option of the `top` clause. It returns all rows which have the same value of their sorting criteria (in our case, they are first in their groups):

```
select top (1) with ties t.Id, g.GoalValue
from @Tbl t
    left join @Goals g on t.Id = g.Id and t.BeginDate between g.StartDate and g.EndDate
order by row_number() over(partition by t.Id order by g.StartDate);
```

However, this solution isn't very flexible; in particular, you can't sort it without nesting it into a subquery. Personally, I would prefer a correlation:

```
select t.Id, oa.GoalValue
from @Tbl t
    outer apply (
        select top (1) g.GoalValue from @Goals g
        where g.Id = t.Id
            and t.BeginDate between g.StartDate and g.EndDate
        order by g.StartDate
    ) oa;
```

Depending on whether you need rows with no range matches, you can switch between `outer` and `cross` versions of `apply`; the rest of the query stays the same. Also, it gives you complete freedom in defining matching criteria, in case you will come up with any at some later time.

Answer (score 0):

using **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** to number the rows restarting from 1 for each `partition`. In this case if we partition by `b.Id, b.BeginDate` then every time that row is repeated (across `goal` date ranges), it increments by 1. We can use `where rn=1` to remove all of those extra matches like so:

```
select Id, GoalValue
from (
  select a.ID, g.GoalValue
    , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by b.Id, b.BeginDate
      order by g.StartDate
      )
  from Table1 a
  join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
  left join Goals g on g.ID = b.ID
          and b.BeginDate between g.StartDate and g.EndDate
)
where rn = 1
```